# Subversion Web administration

Tags: php, svn, web, administration

Looking for a Subversion web administration tool (preferably written in PHP), done some googling but most of the ones I have found don't seem to be in active development and I'm not sure which ones to try.

Does anyone use any of them and have any advice on which is the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [USVN](http://www.usvn.info/en). (User-friendly SVN).

Basic features:

> **Users administration:** Simple groups and users administration. Users are
>   the same for the repositories and the web interface.
>
> **Repositories administration:** Simple repositories administration.
>
> **Repositories browsing:** Repositories browsing and files preview from the
>   web interface.
>
> **Rights management:** Simple rights administration. By repositories and by
>   folder in repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Not written in PHP, but [SvnEdge](http://www.collab.net/svnedge) and [UberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) allow managing your repositories from a web browser.

These packages create a repository environment after just running an installer, while packages as USVN are more targetted to hosting multiple repositories yourself.

Comment: UberSVN link is dead. UberSVN is no longer developed and you can't even download it at its official site which is also not available anymore.